# Javascript pattern with jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

I just build a javascript pattern to use jPlayer in web browser. Like this code:

```
var myplayer = {}
myplayer.Controller = (function() {
        var controller;
        var player_state= "default";
        var player  = jQuery('#jquery_jplayer_2');

    function createController(){
        function initial(){
            player.jPlayer({
                solution: "flash, html",
                supplied: "mp3",
                swfPath: "/js"
            });
           }
           function play(){
              player.jPlayer("play");
           }
            return {
              initial:function(){
                  initial();
              },
              play:function(){
                  play();
              }
            }
     }

     return {
         getController:function(){
             if(!controller){
                 controller = createController();
             }
             return controller;
         }
     }
```

and I call it's by var mypl = myplayer.controller.getController().initial();
It's run without any error or warning but not initial jPlayer? Anyone here have an experience on javascript please show me the way, thank you very much!
I also check path to javascript folder and mp3 file is valid. I write alert before call and after call initial function and it run, but still not initial jPlayer. help me please, please!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're being too tricky. Look at the source from this demo

http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/

and use something very similar to that.

Comment: tks shelman, but I need customize to add playlist, control user event, save playlist to cookies ..etc..blah blah and in my case I using jPlayer with two iframe just like we7.com. So I need to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

This code below worked for me so I post here if someone interesting. I'm appreciate any comment from anyone.

```
var mypl = {};
mypl.player = (function(){
    var myplayer;
    var pl = jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer;

    function createPlayer(){
        function initialPlayer(domitem){
            if(domitem == undefined){
                domitem = $("#jquery_jplayer_2"); 
            }
            domitem.jPlayer( {
                ready: function () {
                  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: "url_to_mp3_file"
                  });
                },
                solution: "flash, html",
                supplied: "mp3",
                swfPath: "path_to_swf_file_locate"
              });
        }
        function setMedia(title,filepath){
            jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("setMedia",{name:title,free:true,mp3:filepath});
        }
        function play(){
            jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("play");
        }
        function pause(){
            jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("pause");
        }
        function stop(){
            jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("stop");
        }
        function volume(volume){
            if(volume == undefined || volume  < 0){
                volume = 0.8;
            }
            jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("volume",volume);
        }
        function mute(){
            jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("mute");
        }
        function unmute(){
            jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("unmute");
        }
        function seek(seek){
            if(seek == undefined || seek < 0){
                seek = 0;
            }
            jQuery("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer("playHead",seek);
        }
        return{
            initialplayer:function(domitem){
                initialPlayer(domitem);
            },
            setmedia:function(title,filepath){
                setMedia(title,filepath);
            },
            play:function(){
                play();
            },
            pause:function(){
                pause();
            },
            stop:function(){
                stop();
            },
            mute:function(){
                mute();
            },
            unmute:function(){
                unmute();
            },
            seek:function(){
                seek();
            }
        }
    }
    return{
        getPlayer:function(){
            if(!myplayer){
                myplayer = createPlayer();
            }
            else{
            }
            return myplayer;
        }
    }
})();
```

and I call it like this:

```
var abc = mypl.player.getPlayer();
abc.initialplayer();
```

when you click on some element just call abc.play() or abc.stop(). I still can not make abc.pause() work at this time. Hope to fixed this soon!!
I've changed function name from pause to mypause and function volume too, it run but I still don't know why it run or not!!